# How can I pass multiple variable at the same time on this script

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Now i've changed "?" to "&" already and also add one more variable to "onChange="showBillbyMonth(this.value,selectedYr)" but it still not work.

I have found this script that suit me . However I need to pass 2 variable at the same time.. I've tried but not work. I"m have so limited knowledge of javascript so please help me .. thank you

the script that work on passing one variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showBillbyMonth(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("btxtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }  
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("btxtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","billMonth_view.asp?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

my modified script is below which is not work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showBillbyMonth(str,selectedYr)
{
var xmlhttp;

if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("btxtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }  
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("btxtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","billMonth_view_inYear.asp?q="+str+"&selectedYr="+selectedYr,true)


xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I used with this...

```
<form action="" > 
      <td align="right" >

         <select name="inmonth" id="inmonth" onChange="showBillbyMonth(this.value,selectedYr)">
                                        <option value="">Month</option>
                                        <option value="1">January</option>
                                        <option value="2">February</option>
                                        <option value="3">March</option>
                                        <option value="4">April</option>
                                        <option value="5">May</option>
                                        <option value="6">June</option>
                                        <option value="7">July</option>
                                        <option value="8">August</option>
                                        <option value="9">September</option>
                                        <option value="10">October</option>
                                        <option value="11">November</option>
                                        <option value="12">December</option>
         </select>                                                                                                                                                                           
        </td>       
</form>
```

the script will open below page.. "billMonth_view_inYear.asp"

```
qbill_month = request.querystring("q")
current_year = request.querystring("selectedYr")
```

and continue with sql commmand..somthing like this..

```
sql = "SELECT tbl_bill_total.cust_id, Sum(tbl_bill_total.bill_total) AS sum_bill_total, tbl_customer.cust_name, Month([tbl_bill_total.showndate]) AS bill_month, Year([tbl_bill_total.showndate]) AS bill_year FROM tbl_bill_total INNER JOIN tbl_customer ON tbl_bill_total.cust_id = tbl_customer.cust_id GROUP BY tbl_bill_total.cust_id, tbl_customer.cust_name, Month([tbl_bill_total.showndate]), Year([tbl_bill_total.showndate]) HAVING (((Month([tbl_bill_total.showndate]))="& qbill_month &") AND ((Year([tbl_bill_total.showndate]))="& current_year &"));"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple parameters in a URL, you separate them with `&`, not `?`. `?` is only used to separate the URL pathname from the parameters. So it should be:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","billMonth_view_inYear.asp?q="+str+"&selectedYr="+selectedYr,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to separate two parameter by &.

change

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","billMonth_view_inYear.asp?q="+str+"?selectedYr="+selectedYr,true);
```

by

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","billMonth_view_inYear.asp?q="+str+"&selectedYr="+selectedYr,true);
```

Comment: are you change all desired things in billMonth_view_inYear.asp file.

Answer (score -1):

You are not passing second parameter for the showBillbyMonth(), then how it will work ?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but which part you mentioned to? Coz I think I've already add the second variable into. Thanks

Comment: on this one??   <select name="inmonth" id="inmonth" onChange="showBillbyMonth(this.value)"> but how i suppose to change it? ... "showBillbyMonth(str,selectedYr) ?? but this option have only one value which is str. Sorry i'm not really know well about javascript.